# Connect resque to other key-value DB than redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, couchdb, amazon-simpledb, resque

I just read a little about resque [here](http://github.com/defunkt/resque) and how you use redis as a "advanced key-value store" for the jobs.

As you might know you can use resque on multiple machines to process the jobs:

> Workers can be given multiple queues (a "queue list") and run on multiple machines. In fact they can be run anywhere with network access to the Redis server.

Now my question is... Is resque able to connect to any other key-value database such as SimpleDB or CouchDB? And if yes, does this even make sense?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not able, as it mostly uses Redis' features specifically written for handlin queues, such as `brpop` and `blpush`. CouchDB/SimpleDB's eventual consistency keeps them from being ideal candidates for queues, AMQP implementations, such as RabbitMQ would be suited, but neither usable with Resque.

Comment: Can you explain how eventual consistency nature affect the queue?